# Inspecting variables of running process in C

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, elf

Can anyone help with my research for a uni project...

Can anyone detail the steps taken by GDB when inspecting and printing variables values of an external process?  Does the C stdlib contain this functionally?

Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at this project [linuxdebugger](https://bitbucket.org/Barakat/linuxdebugger/src). There are a number of small samples that may help you.

Comment: Here's something to get you started: (a) find out address of variable by reading debugging info from executable file. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information/ describes how to do this on modern Unix systems (b) use [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) to read from the address.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the manual [GDB Internals Manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/5.1.1/onlinedocs/gdbint.pdf.gz), as well as the [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/).

Answer (score 2):

It is operating system specific. On Linux, GDB would read the debug information (in [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format) from the debug sections of the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable (compiled with e.g. `gcc -g`).

Then it would use some system calls (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for a list) notably [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)

I am surprised that you are asking here. GDB is free software, you can study its source code, then ask on its mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor variables while a program is running could be done by using something like a profiler, but the program would be running much slower than normal. For some embedded or emulator type environments, a debugger can monitor some of the variables in real time. If there are only a few key variables, it may be possible to use a debugger that can set watch points on any write to those variables, which would only slow the program down when those variables get updated.